# Simplify parsed regex

Tags: regex, haskell, graph-theory, abstract-syntax-tree

I have to simplify custom regex expressions parsed to a certain data type. With "simplify" I mean the following (emphasis mine):

> Given the rules:
>
> - lowercase letters match themselves, eg.:
>   `a` matches `a` and nothing else
> - parens enclosing only letters match their full sequence, eg.:
>   `(abc)` matches `abc` and nothing else
> - square brackets enclosing only letters match every letters inside, eg.:
>   `[abc]` matches `a` and `b` and `c` and nothing else
>
> The following are all valid:
>
> - `(a[bc])` matches `ab` and `ac` and nothing else
> - `[a(bc)]` matches `a` and `bc` and nothing else
> - `(a(bc))` is the same as `(abc)` and matches `abc` and nothing else
> - `[a[bc]]` is the same as `[abc]` and matches `a` and `b` and `c` and nothing else
>
> **Regexes can be simplified. For example `[a[[bb]b[[b]]](c)(d)]` is**
> **really just the same as `[abcd]` which matches `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`.**

I have implemented a simple parser combinator in Haskell using `attoparsec` and the following destination data type:

```hs
data Regex
  = Symbol Char
  | Concat [Regex] -- ()
  | Union [Regex] -- []
  deriving (Eq)
```

However, I'm really struggling with the simplification part. I try to reduce the `Concat`s and `Union`s by a combination of unwrapping them, [nubbing](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub) and [concatMapping](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap) to no avail. I think that the data type I have defined might not be the best fit but I have run out of ideas (late at night here). Could you help me look to the right direction? Thanks!

```hs
simplify :: Regex -> Regex
simplify (Symbol s) = Symbol s
simplify (Concat [Symbol c]) = Symbol c
simplify (Concat rs) = Concat $ simplify <$> rs
simplify (Union [Symbol c]) = Symbol c
simplify (Union rs) = Union $ nub $ simplify <$> rs
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your unsuccessful attempt?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I have edited to include my latest committed version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a couple simple improvements, for starters. `simplify (Concat [x]) = x` and likewise for Union: there's no need for the wrapped regex to be specifically a symbol.

Then you need to start looking at `Concat`s containing other `Concat`s, and likewise for `Union`. Sure, you start by simplifying the elements of the wrapped list, but before jamming the result back into a wrapper, you lift up any elements using the same wrapper. Something like:

```
simplify (Concat xs) = 
  case concatMap liftConcats (map simplify xs) of
    [x] -> x
    xs -> Concat xs
  where liftConcats :: Regex -> [Regex]
        liftConcats r = _exerciseForTheReader
```

Then you can do something similar for Union, with a `nub` thrown in as well.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations! It was hard to see at the moment. You were right about the simple improvements as well.

Comment: Since `concatMap` has `map` built in you can write `concatMap (liftConcats . simplify) xs`